# PostgreSQL - psql \watch command - how to interrupt on Windows binary distro (EDB)

Tags: postgresql, psql

The output of `SELECT version();`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

and it's a binary distribution from EnterpriseDB. Might also be using 12 or 13, but I don't imagine it makes much of a difference.

I'm running Windows 10, but I will also be running Linux - any differences to be noted would be appreciated.

The psql `\watch` command is great. If I run

```
SELECT 1 AS "Waste of my time"
\watch 1;
```

then the output is:

```
27/11/2021 07:06:41 (every 1s)

 Waste of my time
------------------
                1
(1 row)

27/11/2021 07:06:42 (every 1s)

 Waste of my time
------------------
                1
(1 row)

&c....
```

which is great. **But**, if I try to stop it by typing `q` or `Ctrl-D` or `Ctrl-Z` - no joy.

The only thing that works is `Ctrl-C` but that has the problem of stopping my server which is a PITA.

How can I interrupt the `\watch` process in a way that just returns me to the `psql` prompt?

Comment: There is no need to use virtual desktops for this (neither the built-in from Windows 10, nor any external tool) if you install Postgres correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do. The reason it happens in the first place is that I don't like having many windows open on 1 desktop so I start the server running in the background and then start the psql tool in the same window.

So, what I did was download Sysinternals virtual desktop utitly - 4 desktops, just like real operating system!

1 - I start my Postgres server from a window on desktop 4.

2 - then I go to desktop 1 (number not important). What is important is that the window that's running psql tool is **NOT** the same as window used to start the server.

3 - run the psql tool from desktop 1.

4 - run my command

```
SELECT 1
\watch
```

5 - let the psql tool run watch for a few seconds

6 - hit Ctrl-C. I fall back into psql prompt. I don't lose my connection to the databases and the server doesn't stop.

I hope this can help somebody with the same problem?